# what ring is represented by $\Bbb Z [G]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've got the question:
 If $H \le G$ for finite group $G$, then prove that $\Bbb Z [H]$ is a subring of $\Bbb Z [G]$.

I actually do not want the answer to this question, I just want to know what $\Bbb Z [G]$ and $\Bbb Z [H]$ mean... I want to solve the qeustion myself but without this information I can't even start. Thanks.

Comment: These are *group rings*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $R$ a commutative ring and $G$ a group, $R[G]$ is an $R$-algebra with $R$-basis given by the elements of $G$ and multiplication on the basis given by the group operation, and multiplication in general is extended $R$-linearly.